# XML Javascript draw donut chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml

I am now trying use XML and JavaScript to create a donut chart.

I tried with this JS coding. But I cant make the XML which can run with the JS.

```js
var SCIENCE = 0;
var ART = 0;
var MATH = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "abc.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {

      var prog = $(this).text();

      $(xml).find('course').each(function() {
        var prog = $(this).text();

        if (prog == "SCIENCE") {
          SCIENCE++;
        } else if (prog == "ART") {
          ART++;
        } else if (prog == "MATH") {
          MATH++;
        }

      });
      visualizeIt();
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
    }
  });
});

function visualizeIt() {
  var total = SCIENCE + ART + MATH;
  var pSCIENCE = (SCIENCE / total) * 100;
  var pART = (ART / total) * 100;
  var pMATH = (MATH / total) * 100;

  var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

  var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

  var cScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]).range([0, 2 * Math.PI])
  data = [
    [0, pSCIENCE, "#3399FF", "SCIENCE"],
    [pSCIENCE, pSCIENCE + pART, "#FF9966", "ART"],
    [pSCIENCE + pART, 100, "#FF99FF", "MATH"]
  ]

  var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(150)
    .outerRadius(220)
    .startAngle(function(d) {
      return cScale(d[0]);
    })
    .endAngle(function(d) {
      return cScale(d[1]);
    });

  var g = vis.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc");

  g.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d[2];
    });

  g.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + " ) ";
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d[3];
    });
}
```

I am still new with XML. I am confused with how to create the XML code which can call with the JS.

Thank you for giving me some advice.

Comment: FYI: there is no "g" in donut chart. So you are asking how to loop over an XML document or what should the XML be? How to loop over it is based on how the XML looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic XML should look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tag>
    <course>SCIENCE</course>
    <course>SCIENCE</course>
    <course>ART</course>
    <course>MATH</course>
    <course>SCIENCE</course>
    <course>ART</course>
    <course>SCIENCE</course>
    <course>ART</course>
    <course>MATH</course>
    <course>MATH</course>
</tag>
```